# Javadoc  коментарии к статичному свойству

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу комментарии

```
        /**
         * The SQL statement to be executed.
         */
        public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
                + TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + _ID + " integer primary key , "
                + NAME + " text not null "
                + ");";
```

получается [image]
как нужно писать чтобы The SQL statement to be executed. отображалось наверху комментария, а не в низу.

Comment: спасибо, сделайте пожалуйста комментарий ответом, чтобы  я мог зарыть вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The SQL statement to be executed" в вашем случае отображается первой строчкой. На то, что IDEA во всплывающей подсказке пишет сначала полное имя класса и сигнатуру выражения перед вашим javadoc-ом, вы повлиять не в силах.

То есть технически, может быть, это можно реализовать плагином к IDEA, но зачем?